# returning vector<string> in c++

Tags: c++

I get: `C:\Documents and Settings\ppp\Pulpit\Zadanie3Infix\main.cpp|72|error: conversion from 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >*' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >' requested|`

and i don't know why. The function suppose to return vector of strings and it does, i used all of these * & and it does not work. Please correct me so it will return this vector.

it works like that s = "(2+23)" it will return it will return vector with tokens.

```
  vector<string> split(string s){
    vector<string>* v = new vector<string>();
    int i = 0; bool b;string el = "";
    while(i < s.size()){

        if(isNotNumber(s.at(i))){
            el = s.at(i);
            v->push_back(el);
            cout<<el<<" to operator"<<endl;
            el = "";
            i++;
        }else{
            while( i <s.size() && !isNotNumber(s.at(i))){//LENIWE WYLICZANIE !!!
                el = el + s.at(i);
                cout<<s.at(i)<<" to liczba"<<endl;
                i++;
            }
            v->push_back(el);
            el = "";
        }
    }
    cout<<"PO while"<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < v->size();i++){
        cout<<v->at(i)<<endl;
    }

    return v;
}
```

and what about that

```
stack<string>* stack = new stack<string>();
```

type specifier before stack ;////////////////

Comment: Change it to "vector<string>* split(string s){". you are returning pointer not by value

Comment: I would suggest doing the opposite of what ArunMu said.  Keep the return value the same, and change the object in the function to match.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: That would be more costly. But the coder has to keep a note that he has to delete the pointer sometime later else it will leak memory.

Comment: @ArunMu The OP really should pass a vector by reference. It's absurd to rely on pointers for this scenario.

Comment: @ArunMu: More costly?  How so?  Likely not in C++03 ([rvo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)), and certainly not in C++11 ([move semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Move_semantics#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors)).

Comment: @ArunMu: It would be less costly, unless both copy elision and move semantics fail. If that happens, then you need a better compiler.

Comment: I don't care about cost, C++ s.. anyway, but i just have to make it work.

Comment: @chrisaycock: I dont see the benefit (pointer or reference) in this case. Its completely personal choice.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley,Mike : If its C++11, then certainly go for move. if c++03 I wouldnt put much faith on whether RVO would kick in or not.

Comment: If you just want to make it work I suggest you take Benjamin Lindley's suggestion. Declare your vector as `vector<string> v` and return it by value. C++ is not Java so stop using `new` on everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `split()` claims to return `vector<string>`, however your return value is `v`. What is `v`? It's

```
vector<string>* v
```

You are attempting to return a *pointer* but your function declaration states that it is not returning a pointer. Actually, there's no need for a pointer at all in your function; just use a regular `vector<string>` or pass in a vector by *reference*:

```
void split(string s, vector<string>& v){
```

Answer (score 3):

The question about whether to return a pointer or a value, or pass in a reference to an existing vector was settled a long time ago: don't do any of the above. Instead, create a generic algorithm that works with iterators:

```
template <class InIt, class OutIt>
void tokenize(InIt b, InIt e, OutIt o) {
    while (b != e) {
        std::string token;
        while (isdigit(*b))
            token.push_back(*b++);
        if (!token.empty())
           *o++ = token;
        while (!isdigit(*b) && b != e)
            *o++ = std::string(1, *b++);
    }
}
```

To put the result in a vector of strings, you'd do something like:

```
std::string i("(2+23)");
std::vector<std::string> tokens;

tokenize(i.begin(), i.end(), std::back_inserter(tokens));
```

Or, if you wanted to display the tokens, one per line for testing:

```
tokenize(i.begin(), i.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

...which will produce:

```
(
2
+
23
)
```

That fits with what I'd think of as the tokens in this input string. I should add, however, that while it works for that input, it may or may not produce what you expect for other inputs. In particular, it will treat whitespace characters as tokens, which you usually *don't* want (but does seem to be how the original was intended to work).

Comment: I would have to disagree that it's settled.  Not everything has to be completely generic. Certainly you would agree that `auto tokens = split("(2+23)");` is much more readable than your suggested method.  That's gotta be worth something.  I think both methods have valid reasons to exist, and perhaps one could make use of the other.

Answer (score 2):

Your function signature returns a vector, but your return value is a pointer. Change the return value type to pointer to vector or return a vector by value in your function body.

Answer (score 1):

This is really Blastfurnace's answer, ...

but convert the line:

```
vector<string>* v = new vector<string>();
```

into

```
vector<string> v;
```

and change all the `v->` into `v.`

This way you fix the memory leak too. (The memory allocated by `new vector<string>()` is never deleted). However, `vector<string> v;` puts the memory on the stack and is automatically deleted when it goes out of scope.